# why i am getting ClassCastException in this case

Tags: java

Please tell me why i am getting ClassCastException in this case

**I have type casted , the source of B class to A as shown below , but why i am still getting ClassCastException here .**

```
public class A extends B 
{


}

public class B {
    public String getData() {
        return "B";
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a = (A) b;
        System.out.println(a.getData());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast a base class to derived class. You can do the other way round though.

Answer (score 2):

It becomes more obvious if we play with different classnames:

```
public class Car extends SomethingWithWheels {}    // was A extends B
public class SomethingWithWheels {}                // was B

public class Train extends SomethingWithWheels {}  // aahh, some C extends B
```

Now, lets cast again:

```
SomethingWithWheels somethingWithWheels = getItFromSomewhere();
Car car = (Car) somethingWithWheels;
```

The compiler has to complain, because `somethingWithWheels` (`B`) could be a `Train` instance (`C`), which can't be cast to `Car` (`A`).

Answer (score 0):

Because an instance of `B` is **not** an instance of `A`.  It's really that simple.

If you create an instance of `A`, it's also a `B` - because that's what the subclassing means.  However, if you create an instance of `B`, that is *not* an `A`, and can't be assigned/cast as such.

The only time you can cast is if the run-time class of an object is compatible with the type you're trying to cast to.  You can't *change* the class of an existing object - which is what I think you might be trying to do here - only tell the compiler "look, I know it's really something more specific".

So as a counter-example, the following would work:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new A();
    A a = (A) b;
    System.out.println(a.getData());
}
```

In this case, the variable `b` is declared to hold a reference to a `B`.  It turns out that you populate it with an instance of `A`, but for the rest of the program the compiler isn't allowed to assume that `b` is an `A`, because it's not guaranteed.  Since you *know* it's an `A` in your specific case, you insert the cast, which causes a run-time check that the object actually is an `A`.  This succeeds, and from that point on you can call methods specific to `A` on your `a` variable.

In this case however there is no reason at all to do any casting - there are no extra methods available on the subclass that you'd need to call, and no methods which only take an `A` but not a `B`.  Even if `A` overrode `getData` to do something different, you would still get this behaviour if invoking through a `B` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because your instance "b" is not of type A (B does not extend A), so when you cast "b" to A it fails.
The opposite would work (casting an instance of type A to type B)

Answer (score 0):

You are downcasting and you try to cast a supertype to a subtype, thats why it does well during compilation but fails at runtime with ClassCastException.

You can call:

```
System.out.println(a.getData());
```

after removing the line where you try to cast the types